# Firebase Storage does not work on real IOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download images from firebase storage in my flutter app. My code works on ios and android emulators but the moment I use a real Iphone to call the firebase storage API I get an output:

**FLTFirebaseStorage: An unknown error occurred while calling method Reference#getData
flutter: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.**

I am not really sure what to do here. Does anyone know a fix?

My firebase versions are:

```
firebase_core: ^2.8.0
firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
firebase_storage: ^11.0.16
```

My code is:

```
Future<Image?> getImage() async {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

// Create a reference with an initial file path and name
    final pathReference = storageRef.child("drr.jpg");
    try {
      const oneMegabyte = 1024 * 1024;
      final Uint8List? data = await pathReference.getData(oneMegabyte);
      // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned, use this as needed.
      if (data != null) {
        return Image.memory(data);
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // Handle any errors.
      print(e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: real iPhone?  Through testflight?  I'm guessing maybe has something to do with: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in your Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like this is an issue with Firebase rules

Go to Firebase Console -> Project -> Storage -> Bucket -> Rules and paste the below code or check if it's the same.

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
      match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if true;
      }
   }
 }
```

Also, try this in **Info.plist**
for iOS 10 support

```
 NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent = Yes
```

for iOS 9 support

```
 NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = Yes
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Unfortunately, they didn't seem to fix the problem. I have noticed people with the same issue mention security rules, but I had them completely open from the start.